# How can I scrape more than 1,000 results from GitHub Marketplace?

Tags: web-scraping, github-actions

I am trying to scrape GitHub Marketplace using Selenium and BeautifulSoup. However, when scraping I am running into an issue when there are more than 1,000 results. Currently, there are 8,719 [actions](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&query=sort%3Apopularity-desc&type=actions&verification=), but the website only displays a max of 1,000 results (50 pages with 20 results per page). I am not using the GitHub API but rather scraping pages. I am aware that there is a [limit of 1,000 results per search](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#ranking-search-results), but I am not searching for any specific item. Would browsing the pages to see total 8,719 results be considered as using the Search API?

Comment: *Would browsing the pages to see total 8,719 results be considered as using the Search API?* this question strikes me as very strange… for what it is worth I guess it would definitely not be considered an API test and it probably doesn’t likely even use said API under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I have found somewhat of a work around. There are sort options: Best Match, Recently added, and Most installed/starred. I sorted each option by ascending or descending. Finding the similarities and differences between these allowed me to retrieve a total of 7,682/8,788 actions.